# How to Post Payload to URL using cURL

Tags: post, curl, payload

Apologies for my ignorance here.

I have the following payload that I need to send to a URL via cURL (Mac Bash).

```
{“requestid":"2323423432",
"partnermatchid":"56d576ee-2d74-4dda-b8ff-d71b34311dd2",
"usercontext":{"ipaddressmasked":"209.252.7.186",
"useragent":"mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.36     (khtml, like 
gecko) chrome/28.0.1500.95 safari/537.36",
"country":"us"},
"pagecontext":{"pagetypeid":"3","numslots":"6"},
"istest":false}
```

Can you help with the command syntax to do that? I tried this, but it's generating weird HTML in Bash and I don't understand what is going on.

```
echo ‘{“requestid":"2323423432",
"partnermatchid":"56d576ee-2d74-4dda-b8ff-d71b34311dd2",
"usercontext":{"ipaddressmasked":"209.252.7.186",
"useragent":"mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.36         (khtml, like 
gecko) chrome/28.0.1500.95 safari/537.36",
"country":"us"},
"pagecontext":{"pagetypeid":"3","numslots":"6"},
"istest":false}’ | curl —data-binary @- http://www.thisistheurl.com
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi

Comment: Thank you! So I continue with the param/value pairs. What happens in the case of a parameter that has more than one value? For example, requestid has one value... But usercontext has several param/value pairs within it.

Comment: I think this would be useful:
http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: curl --form "fileupload=@my-file.txt" https://example.com/resource.cgi

Comment: But I don't have a file. Do I create a file with the data inside and just send that via --form "fileupload=@my-file.txt" ?   Also, how does it know where the file is?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're POSTing JSON data, you need to specify the content type of the request as well.

Try:

```
curl -d '{ "requestid": "2323423432", "partnermatchid": "56d576ee-2d74-4dda-b8ff-d71b34311dd2", "usercontext": {"ipaddressmasked": "209.252.7.186","useragent": "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome / 28.0 .1500 .95 safari / 537.36", "country": "us" }, "pagecontext": { "pagetypeid": "3", "numslots": "6" }, "istest": false }' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" http://url
```

Also in your original post, there are some "fancy quotes" which should be replaced with normal quotes, in case that's what you're trying to use on the command line.